What is the cardinality of the set of all possible wave functions?
I was just thinking about set theory and somehow this question just comes up to my head. 
The cardinality of the set of all function from $\mathbb{R}^m$ to $\mathbb{R}^n$ is $2^{\mathfrak{c}}$. 
However, not all functions from $\mathbb{R}^m$ to $\mathbb{R}^n$ are valid wavefunctions, as not all of them are square integrable. 
So, supposed we only consider square integrable functions, is the cardinality still $2^{\mathfrak{c}}$ ?

This question is similar to: Hilbert space of a free particle: Countable or Uncountable?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Actually the wavefunctions are the elements of a $L^2(R^n)$ space. That space is separable, so to fix an element you have to fix a sequence of complex numbers. The fact that the sequence must converge in $\ell^2$ to a non vanishing number and that one has still to take a quotient with respect to common complex factors do not change the final result: the cardinality is $2^{\mathbb{N}}$.

Assuming that the continuum hypothesis is true, does this mean that we can represent every wave function with a real number?

Yes, quite strange but true, from a mathematical perspective. Actually I suspect that some wavefunctions are not physically meaningful as they have infinite expectation values of important observables like energy. That is a physical reason to reject some naive post measurement states based on the postulate projection of operators with continuous spectrum. However I do not expect that the cardinality changes.

That is quite cool, nonetheless. I wonder if one can find an explicit mapping function, but that might be equivalent to proving the continuum hypothesis, so it's probably not possible. It also means that I am totally wrong about the size of the MWI universes. I always suspected that they had a cardinality of aleph_2, but that is a gross overestimate, then.

@FlatterMann :  Valter's argument does not in any way invoke the continuum hypothesis.

@WillO No, it doesn't, but the statement that the cardinality of the real numbers is aleph_1 seems to require it, so I didn't want to quietly sweep it under the rug since we were talking some non-trivial math here. I Just like the idea that one might be able to label all wave functions (uniquely?) with a real number.

Can't the functional from Hohenberg-Kohn Theorem can be used to "label" the wavefunctions?


Strictly speaking, L^2-space really consists of equivalence classes of functions. Two functions represent the same L^2-function if the set where they differ has measure zero. It is not hard to see that this makes <f,g> an inner product, because <f,f>=0 if and only if f=0 almost everywhere. A good way to think of an L^2-function is as a density function, so only its integral on sets with positive measure matter.

https://mathworld.wolfram.com/L2-Space.html
The set of equivalence classes has cardinality $2^{\mathbb N}$, but the set of functions has cardinality $2^c$ (each equivalence class has $2^c$ members).
